# how to define a gradient function for this function in optim()

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

I'm looking for some advice on my R code for my model fitting. I'm essentially trying to create a function where it models a 3 parameters log-logistic regression (max, ED50, and slope) to fit my data. I've tried to use drc package before, but for our data, I also need to define that ED50 has to follow the Govardoskii opsin curve. Therefore, I'm trying to create the function for curve fitting myself and then let optim() determine the best parameters that produce the least residual sum of squares. This is what I have tried so far:

```
#first create Govardoskii opsin template function
Govardoskii <- function(lmax, abs.factor,lambda){
  abs.stot <- ((exp(69.7*(0.8795+0.0459*exp(-(lmax-300)^2/11940)-lmax/lambda))+exp(28*(0.922-lmax/lambda))+exp(-14.9*(1.104-lmax/lambda))+0.674)^-1+0.26*exp(-((lambda-(189+0.315*lmax))/(-40.5+0.195*lmax))^2))*abs.factor
  
  
  df <- data.frame(lambda, abs.stot)
  return(abs.stot)
}

#secondly create a function with 1 opsin in there
#par1 is max1, par2 is lmax1, par3 is abs.factor1, par4 is slope1
opsin1 <- function(data, par){
  with(data, 
       par1 <- par[1],
       par2 <- par[2],
       par3 <- par[3],
       par4 <- par[4],
       sum(((0+(par1-0)/(1+ (log10(photons)/(Govardoskii(lambda=wavelength, par2, par3)))^(-par4)))
                  -phaseshift)^2))
}


#use optim 
par0 <- c(3,400,1,4)
result <- optim(par0,  fn = opsin1, 
                data = d1)

result
```

This is working for me right now, but the outcome is still far away from ideal. I would also like to set bounds for some parameters so I would like to try L-BFGS-B method instead and provide a gradient function to optim(). I don't entirely understand how to write this gradient function, so this is probably very far off but I have this so far:

```
dpar1 <- D(expression(((0+(par1-0)/(1+ (log10(photons)/(((exp(69.7*(0.8795+0.0459*exp(-(par2-300)^2/11940)-par2/lambda))+exp(28*(0.922-par2/lambda))+exp(-14.9*(1.104-par2/lambda))+0.674)^-1+0.26*exp(-((lambda-(189+0.315*par2))/(-40.5+0.195*par2))^2))*par3))^(-par4)))
                         -phaseshift)^2), "par1")
dpar2 <- D(expression(((0+(par1-0)/(1+ (log10(photons)/(((exp(69.7*(0.8795+0.0459*exp(-(par2-300)^2/11940)-par2/lambda))+exp(28*(0.922-par2/lambda))+exp(-14.9*(1.104-par2/lambda))+0.674)^-1+0.26*exp(-((lambda-(189+0.315*par2))/(-40.5+0.195*par2))^2))*par3))^(-par4)))
                       -phaseshift)^2), "par2")
dpar3 <- D(expression(((0+(par1-0)/(1+ (log10(photons)/(((exp(69.7*(0.8795+0.0459*exp(-(par2-300)^2/11940)-par2/lambda))+exp(28*(0.922-par2/lambda))+exp(-14.9*(1.104-par2/lambda))+0.674)^-1+0.26*exp(-((lambda-(189+0.315*par2))/(-40.5+0.195*par2))^2))*par3))^(-par4)))
                       -phaseshift)^2), "par3")
dpar4 <- D(expression(((0+(par1-0)/(1+ (log10(photons)/(((exp(69.7*(0.8795+0.0459*exp(-(par2-300)^2/11940)-par2/lambda))+exp(28*(0.922-par2/lambda))+exp(-14.9*(1.104-par2/lambda))+0.674)^-1+0.26*exp(-((lambda-(189+0.315*par2))/(-40.5+0.195*par2))^2))*par3))^(-par4)))
                       -phaseshift)^2), "par4")

grr.min.RSS <- function(data, par){
  with(data, 
       par1 <- par[1],
       par2 <- par[2],
       par3 <- par[3],
       par4 <- par[4],
       dpar1 <- dpar1,
       dpar2 <- dpar2,
       dpar3 <- dpar3,
       dpar4 <- dpar4,
       colSums(cbind(par1=dpar1, par2=dpar2, par3=dpar3, par4=dpar4), na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

This is not working right now and producing the error " gradient in optim evaluated to length 1 not 4", I'm not sure how to improve on this anymore and would like to ask if anyone can give me some advice on how to write this gradient function?

Here are some examples of my data if it's needed:

```
phaseshift <- c(-0.09971073,-5.12827516,-1.25581918,-1.85706412,0.25008674,-2.42186561,-3.37136618,-1.87675533,-2.26626844,-3.47082822,3.79248624,-5.21439127,0.71825938,-6.16392402,-5.18114493,-6.84095138,-4.87687650,-1.61899853,-0.04031451,-3.69876694,-0.71338427,-4.83027017,-1.43908716,1.59434147,-0.81446500,-4.44789255,-1.25372162,-1.76663823,-1.94504536,-3.34724953,-2.11232145,-1.88223321,-1.81402033,-0.45866050,-4.16303748,0.54609111,-5.94315292,-1.14197790,4.02222798,2.71761000,-2.23884980,-2.15113826,0.59268672,-3.66570027,-1.00553687,-7.13473028,4.43700268,-3.21499368,-1.92661401,4.62195411,-5.77607256,-4.46313230,-3.11103482,5.10434522,-3.79135447,0.20691684,-0.95613160,6.80237861,6.31075870,-1.39364560,-2.03406523,4.64095777,0.56614407,7.12680962,2.33644234,-2.09369797,3.41460163,-5.08155532,-2.87885852,-0.05124573,2.95949792,-2.93275886,0.38482818,-4.00461845,-3.80600196,-4.37065478,-5.89680598,-3.29185284,-1.59115197,-2.66423758,1.27410917,3.12280863,-2.32960785,-4.82486813,1.22214563,-2.72936335,-1.99178498,-2.70914419,-9.21375631,3.49831542,0.61184124,-2.63044571,-4.32736378,-1.29888099,-2.96927484,1.16906813,-7.60074479,1.19634235,-6.96961599,-0.41553615,3.40084051,-3.65351252,-0.84528194,-3.03585660,3.92968321,-5.79113902,-0.66469332,1.89437353,-5.37929126,-4.68119655,4.67727306,2.15225726,-0.91324808,5.35138702,-1.83813156,-1.49689027,-4.13832921,-4.65783427,-2.87742337,-0.18942768,5.72410389,0.91645489,3.12606467,-3.35580712,0.12559064,5.77978224,-4.32863445,-2.32581900,-3.17198178,4.92533508,-0.66098512,-0.16946025,1.32272128,-4.74037971,1.11168230,-1.75517358,1.96203752,-4.09742028,5.50234090,-2.33842854,-0.44876834,3.54642685,3.57735466,1.79064165,1.26695366,-1.14309068,-1.47917735,2.05132116,-2.73335540,2.13806269,2.82870419,6.68696578,-0.25024150,3.75563680,2.12726556,1.61300979,2.21641236,3.65597049,-2.54424866,3.23691157,-6.11659239,-0.71694627,4.73784788,-1.74229140,-4.63832246,0.97921996,3.00608687,-0.34852733,-2.86958325,-4.21141812,0.17886962,-0.70085953,-1.18411632,-6.51661570,-3.79629188,0.37805509,-1.04588441,-1.26362653,-2.11641242,0.06118658,-2.97699241,4.11161455,-3.44203322,-0.52825106,1.55253891,-3.71991396,2.31712186,2.20856937,-7.85358633,5.81245936,5.63888349,-3.60310496,-6.57163831,-6.53519983,-3.89020841,-4.65883539,-1.50456364,1.33000611,-1.94018596,-0.65636062,-3.60183194,0.70776402,-2.20131052,4.09246572,0.29506372,0.88104109,-2.92954892,-0.44476545,3.99998624,-0.85384275,-0.37093627,0.45167574,0.38751312,-2.23461003,-4.00064106,-3.86600104,-3.11022855,-5.87339629,1.68896060,2.89884480,3.50142064,10.33320805,-0.39911824,3.65128950,-1.49042891,1.36844295,1.49011655,4.38787428,2.07388818,0.13279152,2.43469595,6.37089533,-1.02968797,4.26166502,-3.37529831,-8.75551237,3.05961587,4.65078825,-2.21868365,7.37099584,1.06187030)

photons <- c(59393306,59393306,59393306,59393306,59393306,59393306,59393306,59393306,59393306,59393306,59393306,
             59393306,59393306,59393306,59393306,59393306,59393306,59393306,59393306,59393306,59393306,59393306,
             59393306,59393306,59393306,114322928,114322928,114322928,114322928,114322928,114322928,114322928,114322928,
             114322928,114322928,114322928,114322928,114322928,114322928,114322928,114322928,1967191060,1967191060,1967191060,
             1967191060,1967191060,1967191060,1967191060,1967191060,1967191060,1967191060,1967191060,1967191060,1967191060,1967191060,
             1967191060,14567643249,14567643249,14567643249,14567643249,14567643249,14567643249,14567643249,14567643249,14567643249,14567643249,
             14567643249,14567643249,14567643249,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,
             153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,
             153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,153676731,1165629872,
             1165629872,1165629872,1165629872,1165629872,1165629872,1165629872,1165629872,1165629872,1165629872,1165629872,1165629872,
             1165629872,1165629872,1165629872,1165629872,1165629872,1165629872,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,
             15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,
             15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,15579641671,113000000000,113000000000,
             113000000000,113000000000,113000000000,113000000000,113000000000,113000000000,113000000000,113000000000,113000000000,113000000000,113000000000,
             113000000000,113000000000,113000000000,113000000000,113000000000,113000000000,247029478,247029478,247029478,247029478,247029478,
             247029478,247029478,247029478,247029478,247029478,247029478,247029478,247029478,247029478,247029478,247029478,
             247029478,247029478,247029478,247029478,1486812579,1486812579,1486812579,1486812579,1486812579,1486812579,1486812579,
             1486812579,1486812579,1486812579,1486812579,1486812579,1486812579,1486812579,1486812579,1486812579,1486812579,1486812579,
             1486812579,15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,
             15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,15491753285,
             15491753285,225000000000,225000000000,225000000000,225000000000,225000000000,225000000000,225000000000,225000000000,225000000000,225000000000,
             225000000000,225000000000,225000000000,225000000000,225000000000,225000000000,225000000000,225000000000,225000000000,225000000000)

wavelength <- c(390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,390,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,419,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441,441)

d1 <- data.frame(photons, wavelength,phaseshift)
```

Thank you very much for the help in advance!

Comment: When I call `optim(par0, fn = grr.min.RSS, data = d1)` I don't get the error. Which call produces the error for you?

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment! Indeed it's working now, I'm not sure what went wrong before. But I'm still having problems with setting constraints with optim, I'm using the call     `optim(par0, fn = grr.min.RSS, lower=c(-12, 300, 1, 0), upper = c(12, 700,2,100), method = "L-BFGS-B", data = d1)`     the convergence is successful but the result is still only taking the initial values I'm giving.

Comment: When I call this with the given arguments, I get the result `$par
[1] -12 400   1   4

$value
[1] -12

$counts
function gradient 
       5        5 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"`.